# How can I remove the glow from a pressed slider in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a custom SeekBar in my Android app. When the thumb is pressed, a kind of halo appears around it. The halo also modifies when it is pressed for a long time. I would like to eliminate this halo effect.

I have looked at this SeekBar documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html but do not see anything that can eliminate it.

So, my question is: How can I disable this "halo" effect when the seekbar thumb is pressed? [image]

In this screenshot, you can see the white halo I am trying to eliminate.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: adding SeekBar xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/clip_connect_list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_radius"
    android:background="@drawable/slider_base"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:clickable="true">
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:thumbOffset="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:progressDrawable="@color/transparent"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        >
    </SeekBar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Let me guess, the halo grows as long as you keep the seekbar pressed. Am I right?

Comment: Not quite. There seems to be two layers of "halo" that are used. When the thumb is first pressed, it looks like the screen shot. After a long press, a second layer grows/animates out thumb image, to the boundary of the first halo, so then the halo looks slightly more opaque.

Comment: Can you post the xml of your Seekbar?

Comment: Researching more, I am guessing this behavior is inherited from the theme. I just tried switch from the application style from "Theme.AppCompat" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and the color of the halo goes from white to a kind of translucent black.  So, I guess the question now is, which property of the theme do I modify?

Comment: I guess it is the selector and if I am not wrong it is the ripple effect, take a look and let me know

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but setting the `colorControlHighlight` property to `transparent` on one's theme worked for me:

```
<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- This is necessary to remove outward glow appearing on seekbar -->
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This same color is used for the ripple effect on other UI elements, so user discretion advised.

Answer (score 3):

Can be removed if you use SeekBar `init` from code, like this:

`SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(context, null, 0);`

Some defaults are lost like left right padding, but can be set again with `setPadding`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [Material Slider](https://material.io/components/sliders/android#discrete-slider) you can just use the next properties to handle halo:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Attribute      | Related method(s)                                   | Default value
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app:haloColor  | (setHaloTintList/getHaloTintList)                   | ?attr/colorPrimary at 24%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
app:haloRadius | (setHaloRadiusResource/setHaloRadius/getHaloRadius) | 24dp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```