# How to change or disable the grey highlighting around the seekbar thumb?

Tags: android, seekbar, seekbar-thumb

When im pressing the thumb at my Seekbar, a pale shadow appears around it, like shown below.

[image: Before press and click It.]
[image: How to remove or change pale gray around It.]

How can i remove the shadow or set it transparent?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar).

Comment: Tnx! But that Not help me.

Comment: I found the solution at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452875/how-can-i-remove-the-glow-from-a-pressed-slider-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 6):

add

```xml
android:background="@null"
```

for example:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: It is now that you edited it and provided more context.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unintuitive, but just set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` on the SeekBar.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you change the ripple color, you can change that color. See this [link](https://blacklenspub.com/styling-appcompat-button-fab-with-ripple-effect-c6f811eca2f5) to more information about how to change the ripple color of a button, the same solution maybe useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

it's controlled by `colorControlHighlight`

so

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/seekBarStyle"
            />

    <style name="seekBarStyle">
        <item name="colorAccent">#0394D6</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#22ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    </style>
```

OK the 'highlight' is just a ripple background of the seekbar, which is quite interesting!